# Generate Data Only Script without Identity SQL 2017

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2017

I am using the script generator in SQL 2017 to create an INSERT script.

When generated, it includes the Identity which I don't want.

I have set Script Foreign Keys and Script Primary Keys to false but it is still including them.

My table is:
ID (Identity), machnineno, amount

what I want to create is an INSERT script that looks like

```
INSERT tablename (machineno,amount) values (1789,15)
INSERT tablename (machineno,amount) values (3894,22)
INSERT tablename (machineno,amount) values (2097,9)
```

Currently it is doing

```
INSERT tablename (id,machineno,amount) values (22,1789,15)
INSERT tablename (id,machineno,amount) values (45,3894,22)
INSERT tablename (id,machineno,amount) values (77, 2097,9)
```

How can I generate a script without the ID?

Comment: Do you really want to lose the identity column, or you are just not supplying an specific value and letting the table generate a new one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Disabling to script the primary key and foreign key only restrict the generation of scripts creating these constraints. Identity is a table property. I would suggest (not efficient since duplicating data) to copy the column you required to a new table and script that table.

You can use,

```
Select machineno,amount into tmp_table 
from tablename
```

**Note** the new table created will not create constraints and triggers
or you can script the DDL of the original table and create a dummy table without identity column in it and copy the data to the new table so it will retain the constraints

Then script the tmp_table using generate scripts. This will not have the identity column. You can change the table name as required after you have scripted it.

OR 
Scripting dynamically

```
SELECT 'INSERT INTO tablename (machineno,amount) values ('+convert(varchar(28),machineno)+','+convert(varchar(28),amount)+')'
FROM tablename
```

Comment: that's exactly what I ended up doing. I copied the table, removed the identity and then scripted the table.